# 'all the lawyers standing on the shoulders of the butchers to get a better look'

Tags: phrase-meaning, jokes

> And if all the people who say they were there had really been there,
>   then the dregs of London would have drained to the one spot, the gaols
>   emptied of thieves, the beds empty of whores, and **all the lawyers
>   standing on the shoulders of the butchers to get a better look**.
>
> *Bring Up the Bodies by Hilary Mantel*

Why would the lawyers stand on the shoulders of the butchers to get a better look? Is it because they got nothing to do since there's no clients?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a two-level joke:

- the people who claim to have been include the "dregs" of London, the worst sorts of people, and
- the dregs include the thieves and the whores—and of course the lawyers, who climb on top of the only honest working men in the list to get a good look!

Comment: Thank you. After reading your answer I realized I totally misunderstood this section not just the one part I asked. - -::